# Using fonts in chakra UI in Next js

Tags: next.js, chakra-ui

My application is built using NextJs and uses Chakra UI.
I have installed Google Fonts by following this

[chakra Google fonts](https://chakra-ui.com/guides/using-fonts)

`npm install @fontsource/open-sans @fontsource/raleway`

```
import { extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react"
```

const theme = extendTheme({
fonts: {
heading: "Open Sans",
body: "Raleway",
},
})

export default theme

Now I can use two different fonts,

1. For Body
2. For headings

However, how about using more fonts ?
Say I was to use different fonts for Buttons,
Different for Text.
Also within text, I want to use different fonts for Italic and underlined text portions.

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy to add more fonts using the theme, you just need to add them in `fonts: {}` and then you can reference them by using the chakra variable: `var(--chakra-fonts-xxx)`

For example, if you want to define a font dedicated to subheader:

```
import { extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react";

const theme = extendTheme({
  fonts: {
    heading: "Open Sans",
    subHeading: "Times New Roman",
    body: "Arial Black",
  },
  textStyles: {
    h2: {
      'font-family': 'var(--chakra-fonts-subHeading)',
    },
  }
});

export default theme;
```

Now when you'll create a h2 component (`<Heading as="h2">h2 text</Heading>`), it will use this font.

You'll notice that unfortunately, I had to use `'font-family'` instead of `fontFamily` (it seems to be an existing bug, same for `font-weight`).

Answer (score -1):

To use different fonts in Buttons, you can customize Buttons components from your theme.
in const theme, the same way as fonts you need to create a `components` object:

```js
const theme = extendTheme({ 
    fonts: { 
        heading: "Open Sans", body: "Raleway", 
    }, 
    components: {
        Button: {
            baseStyle: {
                fontFamily: 'yourfont here'
            }
        }
    }
})
```

You can do the same with other state of buttons for example `_hover`, `_focus`, `_isDisabled`, etc.